# For loop - changing index on each iteration

Tags: loops, for-loop, indexing, iteration

I have a list of lists, containing customers, sales and thread sold, I need to append each to a new list :

```
for x1 in trans_clean:
  index = 0 
  customers.append(trans_clean[index]) 
  sales.append(trans_clean[1])
  thread_sold.append(trans_clean[2])
```

customers needs to start from index 0 and jump by 4, so 0,4,8,12,16 etc.
sales at 1
thread_sold at 2

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post what language your working in.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language your working in but it sounds like your trying to iterate the index for each time it is used. This should do what your trying to achieve:

```
index = 0
for x1 in trans_clean: 
  customers.append(trans_clean[index]) 
  index = index + 4
  sales.append(trans_clean[1])
  thread_sold.append(trans_clean[2])
```

If I knew what language you were working in I could probably give you a cleaner syntax. For instance you might just be able to use the index of the array your are looping through multiplied by 4. But I think the concept of what I am doing should make sense.